# CD4 Proteins & Antigen presenting cells

Tags: immunology, antigen, mhc

If Helper T-Cells express CD4+ proteins on their surface to bind to MHC Class ll proteins on antigen presenting cells, why do antigen presenting cells also have CD4+ Proteins?

Comment: This question has been asked previously. You can click on this link to get furthur information - https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/67948/11647